# jquery AppendGrid with dynamic data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jquery appendGrid plugin.

```
  $(function () {
// Initialize appendGrid
$('#myTable').appendGrid({
    caption: 'Manage Field Specifications',
    initRows: 1,
    columns: [
            { name: 'SourceField', display: 'Source Field', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 5 }, ctrlCss: { width: '90px'} }
        ]
});
```

myTableData = [
            { "SourceField": "SRCFLD1"}];

```
// Fetch the data to show in the grid;
$('#myTable').appendGrid('load', myTableData);
```

This is working fine if i provide the hard coded data in "myTableData".
but when i make the data to fetch from a hidden field / some other content from the same page, the grid is behaving unexpectedly.

say, myTableData = document.getElementById("myHiddenDataForTable").value;

If I provide this kind of data, the table is behaving unexpectedly and is showing a lot of empty rows added.

Assist me in getting the dynamic data for the table and the table works properly with the supplied dynamicdata.

Thanks,

Sen

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myTable').appendGrid({
        caption: 'Manage Field Specifications',
        initRows: 0,
        columns: [
                { name: 'Album', display: 'Album', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '160px'} },
                { name: 'Artist', display: 'Artist', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '100px'} },
                { name: 'Year', display: 'Year', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 4 }, ctrlCss: { width: '40px'} },
                { name: 'Origin', display: 'Origin', type: 'select', ctrlOptions: { 0: '{Choose}', 1: 'Hong Kong', 2: 'Taiwan', 3: 'Japan', 4: 'Korea', 5: 'US', 6: 'Others'} },
                { name: 'Poster', display: 'With Poster?', type: 'checkbox' },
                { name: 'Price', display: 'Price', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 10 }, ctrlCss: { width: '50px', 'text-align': 'right' }, value: 0 }
            ]
    });



    // Prepare demo data
    var AlbumCount = 0, AlbumData = [];
    for (var z = 0; z < 500; z++) {
        AlbumCount++;
        AlbumData[z] = { 'Album': 'Album ' + AlbumCount, 'Artist': 'Artist ' + AlbumCount, 'Year': 2008 + Math.round(Math.random() * 5), 'Origin': 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 5), 'Poster': Math.random() > 0.5, 'Price': 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) / 10 };
    }

    // Load data to grid

    $('#myTable').appendGrid('load', AlbumData);
```

Please use this sample code to load data into the Grid.

Comment: Thanks Monish for ur reply.
I am able to provide data through this method what you have suggested.
But when i integrate with the actual application, the grid data is getting added when the page is loaded. By then, the table is initialized and is showing with unexpected results.

please suggest me to get live / dynamic data to the grid.

Thanks,
Sen